# How to set charset encoding property for SVN File and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, utf-8

I have a file which has international characters (UTF-8). How so I set this encoding type as a part of svn property and how do I ensure that it overrides automatically default encoding in eclipse i.e. eclipse should automatically set UTF-8 encoding based on the svn property (may be mime-type).

Comment: Maybe related: [How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9180981/2932052)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

svn propset svn:mime-type "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" filename...

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, but solved by setting below:

Set Encoding in Eclipse:
Project --> Properties --> Resources --> Text File Encoding --> Other (UTF-8)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181068/2932052

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a while, and have found another solution. If you're using maven you can set the encoding in the pom. see https://maven.apache.org/general.html.

After you've added this, when you do a Maven > Update Project (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) it will set the correct encoding for the project.

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SVN, I don't know but you can set text file encoding on each file individually: right-click on the file, go to properties and in the resource submenu check 'Other' for Text File Encoding.

Comment: My requirement is eclipse should auto pickup contenttype/char encoding of the SVN File,I dont want to set it manually.