# how can i get the Unicode infinity symbol converted to String

Tags: java, string, numbers

I want to use the infinity symbol (8 lying sideways) in java.

furthermore i want to use it as a String component.
i did not find a working charcode/ascii code for this (is there any?).

i tried:

```
String s=Character.toString(236);
String s=Character.toString('236');
```

am i missing something?

i got this now:

```
System.out.println(Character.toString('\u221E'));
```

but the output is `?`

i am using java 1.7 jdk and eclipse. why is the infinity sign not showing up?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the Unicode infinity sign, [U+221E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm). 236 is a Windows typing convention, that won't help you at all. `'\u221e'` is the character constant.

Now, I can't promise that this will result in any ∞ characters on your screen. That depends on what sort of computer you have, what font you are using, and what you set in -Dfile.encoding. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding).

Comment: using this i receive `?`. the infinity symbol cannot be shown by default? if this is the case the question is obsolete because my teacher will compile the code at his own pc resulting in the same default output (if it is default)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late reply but the below information will definitely help someone.

In <kbd>**Eclipse**</kbd> by default Text File encoding for console is <kbd>**Cp1252**</kbd>, then

[How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)

and I will encourage to handle the `infinity` symbol in `String` like below source:

```
String infinitySymbol = null;

try {

    infinitySymbol = new String(String.valueOf(Character.toString('\u221E')).getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

    infinitySymbol = "?";
    //ex.printStackTrace(); //print the unsupported encoding exception.

} finally {

    System.out.print("Symbol of infinity is : " + infinitySymbol);

}
```