# How to make an infinity sign on Android?

Tags: java, android, formatting, infinity

I know there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806893/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-infinity-symbol-converted-to-string), but `'\u221e'` doesn't work for me. Also this is Android-specific. Surely there must be a way to show an infinity sign!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Never mind, found it myself:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getInfinity()
```

Note that it may not work with some custom fonts.

Comment: I use this code in the contains method as a regex and works fantastic.
<string name="infinity">&#8734;</string> I cant use in regex as infinity sign.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new item in "strings.xml":

```
<string name="infinity">&#8734;</string>
```

And then call it using your Context:

```
textView.setText(context.getString(R.string.infinity));
```