# akka github source contains unprintable characters

Tags: github, akka

i downloaded akka source from github. i find that many files have these junk characters in them.

=> converts to â‡’

<- converts to â†�

```
trait OnlyCauseStackTrace { self: Throwable â‡’
  override def fillInStackTrace(): Throwable = {
    setStackTrace(getCause match {
      case null â‡’ Array.empty
      case some â‡’ some.getStackTrace
    })
    this
  }
}
```

This is present in every version. akka-master, akka-releasing-2.2-M2 , akka-release-2.1

these give error when i import the code into eclipse after generating an eclipse project from sbt

How i download: i download the `zip` file from github website. i cannot use eclipse to import from github as i am behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're probably just not editing them using UTF-8 (as they are in): https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/AkkaBuild.scala#L575

Comment: you mean akka code is written in UTF-8 and not in plain text? i am using eclipse. how do i workaround this problem? i see junk characters in eclipse and i cannot compile it.

Comment: can someone please help me compile akka source code in eclipse? what are the steps. I will be eternally grateful for your kindness.

Comment: No, it's plain text alright. But the character encoding is UTF-8.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-in-eclipse