# Eclipse character encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding, special-characters, java.util.scanner

I am using Scanner to scan a .txt document in Java.  However, when I open the .txt document in Eclipse, I notice some characters are not being recognized, and they are replaced with something that looks like this:

�

These characters won't even let me scan the file as

```
    while(scan.hasNext)
```

automatically returns false (if these characters are not present, then I can scan the document just fine).

So, how do I get Eclipse to recognize these characters so I can scan?  I can't manually remove them because the document is quite large.
Thanks.

Comment: It means the file has non-printable characters in it, or character set you're using (probably the default) isn't what that file is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The file you are reading must be containing UTF-8 or some other encoding characters and when you try to print them on console then you will get some characters as �'. This is because the default console encoding is not UTF-8 in eclipse. You need to set it by going to Run Configuration -> Common -> Encoding -> Select UTF-8 from the drop down. Check below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In your image, it says "Default - inherited (UTF-8)". Is it not UTF-8 then?

Comment: @GregT Yes in this case as mentioned in the answer, it is some other encoding than UTF-8

Comment: By default Run Configuration's enconding inherits workspace's settings. You might be better off changing entire Workspace charset to UTF-8 (Menu>Windows>Preferences: in tab: General>Workspace) as per @HeavyE answer.

Answer (score 26):

If you need to change the character encoding for your entire Eclipse Workspace, go to Window -> Preferences.
Then under General -> Workspace, change the 'Text file encoding' to the appropriate character encoding (in this case, UTF-8).

[image: Eclipse Preferences - Changing Character Encoding]

Answer (score 0):

If non of the previous answers worked, you could solve that issue by changing your **Region settings** if you're using Windows 11 OS.

[Take a look a here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75648170/20504845)