# Java character replacement

Tags: java, replace

I have problem of replacing "…" in java. This is driving me crazy.

It seems that java can't recognize "…" by replace method. What should I try?

I tried

```
    line = line.replace("…", "");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to replace three dot characters, or the single character of the ellipsis? (U+2026)

Comment: @JonSkeet the single character

Comment: Could you post example code that we could use to reproduce your problem because it seems to be working as it should http://ideone.com/E0eNNi.

Comment: What happens if you try `line = line.replace("\u2026","");`?

Comment: @Pshemo      <thetext>Which message would have priority over which other message?
This could get very complicated for little gain …</thetext>       Take this as an input and replace the ... at the end. The "..." should be a single character

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am very sure that I didn't use three dots it is a single character.

Comment: `<thetext>Which message would have priority over which other message? This could get very complicated for little gain …</thetext>` seems to be working as it should http://ideone.com/d27dcG

Answer (score 0):

Try this redirect: [Eclipse character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385818/eclipse-character-encoding)

This isn't exactly related, but it is a setting in eclipse that you should check nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely having a Unicode translation issue. Try using "\u2026" instead of the literal ellipsis character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm and [Creating Unicode character from its number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number). You can not always control how unicode characters will be interpreted in your source code beyond the ASCII set. It is generally a good idea to use escapes for such characters.

Answer (score 0):

The String.replaced only char in the older javas, but nowadays also can replace strings (literally without regex patterns).

The problem you might have encountered, is that of wrong encoding. The encoding of the .java source in the editor versus the compiler's encoding. If you pasted the ellipsis, something might go wrong too.

So use the escaped ASCII representation. You can find the code in the system accessory Character Map:

```
line = line.replace("\u2026", "");
```

Also the line must have been read with the correct encoding. Do not use FileReader, but use another class where one can add explicitly the encoding.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

Instead of the encoding UTF-8 it could be some platform dependent code like Cp1252.

Comment: What do FileReader and BufferedReader have anything to do with the question. The point about encoding is valid though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist if the line contained a wrongly encoded ellipsis, it could go wrong too.

Comment: Agreed. As a general safety percaution, you could not be more right. I am just saying that the question is not talking about reading anything from a file.