# Scanner can't interpret path to file correctly

Tags: encoding, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with Scanner. In my program I ask user to enter path to file, and then read from it using DataInputStream. If user enter path with polish characters, Scanner can't read it properly, e.g : path = "C:żółw\plik" is interpreted as "C:��w\plik". There is also problem with space, path: "a b\plik" is interpreted as "b\plik". Is there any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the encoding of your IDE

On Windows the default encoding for Eclipse is Cp1252 for example.
UTF-8 should do it for polish.
If you use Eclipse then this might help you: [Eclipse character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385818/eclipse-character-encoding)