# Printing UTF-8 in java

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm attempting to print a deck of cards to system.out, with the suits represented by ♥, ♦, ♣, and ♠. I've copy-pasted the characters into my code:

```
deck.offer(new Card(v, (i == 0) ? "\u2666" : (i == 1) ? "♦" : (i == 2) ? "♣" : "♠"));
```

As you can see, I've tried escaping the symbols and directly pasting them into my code. Eclipse (the IDE that I use) gave me the option to change the encoding of the .java file to UTF-8, but my System.out.print()'s still show '?' as the symbols.

How do I print ♥, ♦, ♣, and ♠ to the terminal?

EDIT: Oleski answered my question below. Thank you!

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Maybe you have to configure your terminal to UTF-8. Look in the options.

Comment: You should check your console/terminal to see what code pages it supports. EG PC473 the original IBM code page contains these characters, but at different codes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display special characters using System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933620/display-special-characters-using-system-out-println)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the terminal you're viewing the characters in is not interpreting them as UTF-8. That is, the characters are encoded in UTF-8 correctly, but the terminal is not set to interpret them as UTF-8

Comment: This is the issue. A quick duckduckgo search got me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385818/eclipse-character-encoding#17385876) page, which fixed my problem. Thank you!

Also, to anyone trying to find the Run Configurations menu, it's not under Preferences. It's under the Run menu.