# %d displays question mark ? instead of number

Tags: java, eclipse

When I use %d it displays question mark ? instead of number

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Comparison {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;
    System.out.println("Value of x");
    x = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("value of y");
    y = input.nextInt();
    if (x == y)
      System.out.printf("%d=%d%n", x, y);
    if (x != y)
      System.out.printf("%d not equal %d%n", x, y);
    if (x <= y)
      System.out.printf("%d x<=y %d%n", x, y);
  }
}
```

This is console below

```
 Value of x
 77
 value of y
 77

 ??=??
 ?? x<=y ??
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm Please read some basics hear

Comment: Have you checked if -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 is set in your JVM property?

Comment: i use ellipse photon

Comment: It might be about your IDE eclipse.

Comment: IDE eclipse yes

Comment: Try the answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385818/eclipse-character-encoding

Comment: thank you TiiJ7  you it works , and thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Intellij.

So code is correct.

Try to update your IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is work good in Eclipse Release 4.7.0 (Oxygen) Last revised June 28, 2017.

So you can view your properties for IDE like -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8