# JAVA Sqlite cyrillic letters displayed as?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, cyrillic

I'm working on a class assignment. I have to store data in sqlite and data is in Cyrillic. When I use 3rd party software to browse sqlite database i see text in proper Cyrillic. But when I retrieve data with java I get ?????? (question marks).

I use sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SQLiteDataSource ds = new SQLiteDataSource();
ds.setEncoding("UTF_8");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: here is how i connect to sqlite db:

`Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
stm = conn.createStatement();`

how do i implement your solution in it?

Comment: `Class.forName(org.sqlite.JDBC.class.getCanonicalName());
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:test.db";
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setEncoding(SQLiteConfig.Encoding.UTF8);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, config.toProperties());`

Comment: Ok I've found what was the problem and it was not java sqlite jdbc encoding issue. I was eclipse. I've found solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21434836/2470538](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21434836/2470538)