# How to avoid parsing strange characters

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax

While I am processing XML file, the Stax parser encountered the following line:

```
<node id="281224530" lat="48.8975614" lon="8.7055191" version="8" timestamp="2015-06-07T22:47:39Z" changeset="31801740" uid="272351" user="Krte�?ek">
```

and as you see there is a strange character at the end of the line, and when the parser reaches that line the program stops and gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError  
at [row,col]:[338019,145]

Message: Ungültiges Byte 2 von 2-Byte-UTF-8-Sequenz.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown 
Source)
at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Is there any thing I should change in the settings of Eclipse to avoid that error?

**Update**

code:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader parser = null;
        try {
            parser = factory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "newParser",
                    "e/createXMLStreamReader: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not about `eclipse`, but it is about encoding of your file. There are two cases:

1) file is corrupted, i.e. it contains incorrect symbols, not from defined encoding

2) file is not in `utf-8` encoding and it is defined in `xml` header. So you should check, that you are reading file contents appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you edited and saved your XML file in `eclipse`, this can be a problem in case your `eclipse` is not configured to use `UTF-8`. Check this question: [How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)

Otherwise you probably don't need to do anything about your code. You just need a correctly `UTF-8`-encoded content.