# Android and Java - Unable to encode - encrypt - decode - decrypt string

Tags: java, android, encryption

My desktop application (written in Java) encrypts a file for an Android application.

A string portion from the entire file:

..."*A kerékpár (vagy bicikli) egy emberi erővel hajtott kétkerekű jármű. 19. századi kifejlesztése*"...

read from a file:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("cycles.txt");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, inputCharset));
String read;

while((read=br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(read); 
}
```

After reading the entire file, I encrypt it:

```
String text = sb.toString();
Encrypter er = new Encrypter();
byte[] bEncrypt = er.encrypt(text);
```

After the encryption I encode it to base64:

```
bEncrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bEncrypt);
text = new String(bEncrypt, "ISO-8859-1");
```

After this, the file is saved on my PC's disk:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/files/encr_cycles.txt");
try {
      PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      pr.print(text);
      pr.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

From the Android application I read the file:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("files/encr_cycles.txt"), "ISO-8859-1"));

// Read line by line
String mLine;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(mLine);
}
```

Decode and decrypt:

```
byte[] dec = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] data= new Decipher().doFinal(dec);
String text= new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");
```

And the given text is:

"*A kerékpár (vagy bicikli) egy emberi er?vel hajtott kétkerek? járm?. 19. századi kifejlesztése*"

Note the "?" in the string? Some of the characters aren't decoded correctly.

Q1: What did I do wrong?

Q2: Am I using a wrong charset?

Comment: It looks like you encoded Turkish into ISO-8859-1; that isn't something you want to do. Use `UTF-16`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the charset to "UTF-8" all over the applications (desktop & mobile). The problem was with the root file. The file wasn't saved in "UTF-8".

What did I done in eclipse:

1. Open the root file (.txt) in eclipse (drag & drop the file in the editor)
2. Insert your string or do some changes (blank chars) in the file (in my case the string which cannot be encoded)
3. Press save (CTLR + S), and a dialog will prompt to: **SAVE AS UTF-8**
4. Remove your line
5. Save again

The other solution is to save your file automatically while editing:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default 
encoding for all content types.
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".
```

Source: [How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)