# Read all .txt file in one folder, then copy text (based from line) to another .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write Python code to read all .txt files from one directory then copy it (based from line) to another .txt file:

```
import os
import glob

path = '/Users/Documents/*.txt'
f1 = open(os.path.expanduser('/Users/Documents/test.txt'),'w')
for data in glob.glob(path):
    with open(data) as script:
    for line in script:
        script.readline()
        if 'Subject: ' in line:
           f1.write(line)
```

My code was working, but it can only copy some text from the files, the rest gives an error message, like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1658: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix this? Anyone?

Comment: do your files contain non-ascii characters? Use `codecs.open()` then

Comment: all my .txt file, its contain bunch of people typing in newsgroup, they usually typing in ascii characters, but i trying your suggestion, still give me the error.

Comment: you did mention the `encoding` as `utf-8` right?

Comment: Silly question, but did you write (paste) the script in a non- plaintext editor? This is typically what happens then.

Comment: @martianwars yes i did.

Comment: @JacobVlijm i am using eclipse, is that okay?

Comment: I never use Eclipse, but could you try pasting it in a plain text editor? Else check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse Normally, you shouldn't have to set encoding in a script.

Comment: @JacobVlijm i try your suggestion, and its work, i didn't get any error message, i try pasting it in a plain text editor, but still, for total 1000 .txt file, it didn't take all data, only half or quarter from total data (depends on word). btw, thank you!

Comment: Great! Looking at your code, you have an indentation error, and script.readline() shouldn't be there (is unnecessary). Would you mind if I make it an answer tomorrow? (Am on mobile currently)

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, i don't mind.