# Unexpected error in simple Java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning Java, and I wanted to make a very basic calculator. But looks like I got a problem right a way!

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int test = 6;
        if(test != 9){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

So in Eclipse I tried to run this but the problem is it does not work and show this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>
> at apples.main(apples.java:4)

Comment: You posted only a part of your error. Please post the full error.

Comment: which is line 4?

Comment: Java convention: User uppercase for class names.

Comment: Except for the random non-printing character right at the end [this compiles fine](https://ideone.com/e1FR2G).

Comment: @hellzone its convention. it wont throw any compilation errors.

Comment: @driatiadroup you need to post the entire error log for others to help

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare Thats what I wrote lol. I didn't say it will throw exception but its an important thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no compilation error, just noticed last } is having some invisible character with it. delete it and type again }. Hopefully  it should work. 
It works for me.

Comment: I don't know whom make your answer negative but your answer was true... But I tried other code (which I added it to the question instead of the previous one) and it gets me the same error. So what is your suggestion about that ?! Thanks

Comment: It says `Syntax Error on token "Invalid character", delete this token`

Comment: But whenever I try to delete the **}** and add another , it happens again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse  refer this link for utf 8 slandered. looks like your eclipse has some different setting.

Answer (score 3):

Your second last bracket has some invisible character that you can see a red point(very thin) and if you delete the same your program is perfectly ok.

**Incorrect Code having special character in it**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class AdvanceCollection {
     public static void main(String args[]){
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                double fnum, snum, answer;
                System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
                fnum = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                snum = scan.nextDouble();
                answer = fnum + snum;
                System.out.println(answer);
     }﻿
     }
```

**Correct code with out that issue**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdvanceCollection {
 public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            double fnum, snum, answer;
            System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
            fnum = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
            snum = scan.nextDouble();
            answer = fnum + snum;
            System.out.println(answer);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your character at the end to `}`.

Comment: The error is `java: illegal character: \65279`,  `java: reached end of file while parsing.`