# DynamoDB automatically converting special characters

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

Working with DynamoDB and AWS (.net C#). For some reason when saving strings containing "é" get replaced with a question mark when saved.

How can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB stores strings in UTF-8 encoding. Somewhere in the your application you must be assigning that string in something other than UTF-8.

Im using Java (which uses UTF-16). I don't do anything special when storing strings. I just tried storing and retrieving "é" in DynamoDB using the Java SDK and there was no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answer, your IDE will generally have encoding settings. You'll want to change the string encoding for your project to UTF-8 to minimize the changes of an encoding error, which can create what is thought to be an unknown string.

For example, in Eclipse editors, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse) to change your encoding.