# why I am not able to format the currency of other two countries China and France

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting

I am able to format the currencies of US and India. I have tried the few implementations using the Localebuilder ,Can anyone please explain what ia m missing.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.math.*;
 import java.util.regex.*;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.Locale;

 public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
    scanner.close();

    // Write your code here.

    NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    System.out.println("US: " + us.format(payment));

    Locale indiaa = new Locale("en", "IN");
    NumberFormat india = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indiaa);
    System.out.println("India: " + india.format(payment));

    Locale chinaLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("zh").setRegion("CN").build();
    NumberFormat china = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(chinaLocale);
    System.out.println("China: " + china.format(payment));


    NumberFormat france =  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    System.out.println("France: " + france.format(payment));
    }
    }
```

The Output I am getting

```
    US: $12,324.13
    India: Rs.12,324.13
    China: ?12,324.13
    France: 12?324,13 ?
```

Expected Output

```
    US: $12,324.13
    India: Rs.12,324.13
    China: ￥12,324.13
    France: 12 324,13 €
```

I am still a beginner
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the problem and question you have.

Comment: I added expected vs what I am getting and I clearly mentioned all the code I am using and I mentioned in the question itself about the two countries.

Comment: Could be a font problem; maybe your font has no euro sign.

Comment: Can you say where you are running your code? Are you using the command line? Eclipse? IntelliJ?

Comment: @another-dave I am running it on hacker rank. My code is not showing any errors. Do you think not having euro sign would be the problem

Comment: @Freiheit  If I run it on eclipse even Indian currency is not showing up

Comment: @Freiheit    123
US: $123.00
India: ? 123.00
China: ?123.00
France: 123,00 €

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  Yeah, I tried your code too, I think some font problem. Because when I use ur code, I am not getting the currency for India and China

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  yeah, I got it after changing the settings in eclipse. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no field for INDIA in [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and therefore, you need to create a custom `Locale` for INDIA. But I do not see any such problem with `CHINA` and `FRANCE` which you have mentioned. Please look at the output of the following program:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter an amount: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.close();

        Locale indiaLocale = new Locale("en", "IN");

        NumberFormat us     = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        NumberFormat india  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indiaLocale);
        NumberFormat china  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
        NumberFormat france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

        System.out.println("US: "     + us.format(payment));
        System.out.println("India: "  + india.format(payment));
        System.out.println("China: "  + china.format(payment));
        System.out.println("France: " + france.format(payment));
    }
}
```

A sample run:

```
Enter an amount: 200.34
US: $200.34
India: ₹ 200.34
China: ￥200.34
France: 200,34 €
```

**Update:**
If you are still facing the issue, it may be because of settings in your eclipse IDE. Check if [How to support UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse) helps you.

Comment: I did create Locale for India. But when i am running the code my output is as I mentioned above

Comment: I tried Arvinds code at https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ and it works correctly.

Comment: @Freiheit   I think it is the font problem because when i try Arvinds code on eclipse still I am not getting the proper output

Comment: @Freiheit  Enter an amount: 123
               US: $123.00
             India: ? 123.00
               China: ?123.00
               France: 123,00 €