# How to configure Eclipse can read Thai language in java code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with reading the Thai language from code java below:

```
if(objArr[22].toString().equals("MISS")){
    LOGGER.info("This is นางสาว." + objArr[6].toString());
    byte[] bytes = "นางสาว.".getBytes();
    String title = new String(bytes);
    classAttendanceDetailDTO.setAgentName(title + objArr[6].toString());
} else if(objArr[22].toString().equals("MR")){
    LOGGER.info("This is นาย." + objArr[6].toString());
    byte[] bytes = "นาย.".getBytes();
    String title = new String(bytes);
    classAttendanceDetailDTO.setAgentName(title + objArr[6].toString());
} else if(objArr[22].toString().equals("MRS")){
    LOGGER.info("This is นาง." + objArr[6].toString());
    byte[] bytes = "นาง.".getBytes();
    String title = new String(bytes);
    classAttendanceDetailDTO.setAgentName(title + objArr[6].toString());
} else{
    LOGGER.info("Not have title");
    classAttendanceDetailDTO.setAgentName("-" + objArr[6].toString());
    }
```

When I print text in the console log with Thai language, the log will show strange language ???? like below :
[image]

Anyone can help me config to read the Thai language in this code?
I also set UTF-8 for default encoding but it is inefficient.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The encoding you used is wrong. You need to use UTF-8 mode. Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Content Types`, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9180981/8242447 can help you.

Comment: I used UTF-8 for all content types as you said with this blog: https://stijndewitt.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/ but it is inefficient

Comment: Did that solve your question?

Comment: Setting the encoding for the `Text` content type does not set it for all the subtypes, like Java source files. And is there a reason you're converting the text to bytes and then back into a String? That potentially makes it subject to a different character set conversion when executing.

Comment: @nitind : I try coding `String s = "นางสาว"; System.out.println(s);` but it also print ??? in log

Comment: This problem can be caused by complier javac, anyone know how to set javac-encoding UTF-8 ?

Comment: Check that the font used by the console can actually display these characters (Preferences - General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Debug > Console font)

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use `javac` unless you are using an external build system like Maven, Gradle, or Ant.