# my code is gone can somehow, is there a way to restore it?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a Maven project for a long time on eclipse where this specific class **App.java** is turned to some empty square blocks. It only happened to that class in the whole package. The code was saved I'm sure. I restarted my laptop and the code looks like this now:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqjh.jpg)

Can anyone help with such an problem? What could have happened? 
I already looked into Restore from Local History option but it will be a big loss of progress.
so is there another way I could restore it?

Comment: That looks like a file encoding issue. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse/42365557

Comment: It wasn't this and I found no other way solve this problem actually. I re-wrote the code anyway :(