# WSO2 MI is replacing Turkish Characters even if charset=UTF-8 in the request json

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

WSO2 MI 1.1.0 seem to be corrupting Turkish characters even if charset=UTF-8 in the request.

I created the following basic API with WSO2 Integration Studio: 7.0.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <api context="/test" name="Test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/test"> <inSequence> <log level="full"/> <respond/> </inSequence> <outSequence/> <faultSequence/> </resource> </api>
```

Here is how I performed the test. ( Simply an HTTP call with charset=UTF-8 in the request.)

[Test Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOe5F.png)

The log also indicate corrupt characters.

[Log Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJp2.png)

I tried using CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING as well. But charset encoding seem to be UTF-8 by default. ( I tried  getting CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING axis property without overwriting and it is UTF-8.

Am I missing something or is there any bug?

Regards.

Comment: I have deployed the same API in mi 1.1.0 and send the request with the payload {"name":"ABDÜLHAMİT"}.  I did not observe any issues with the logged payload. Could you share the payload that you are using in-text rather than the image? Also please try the above payload as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input @ShanakaPremarathna. Your payload is ok to check the problem as well. I resolved my problem by updating encoding for Integration Studio to utf-8. You may check my answer as well. 
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time, I identified that the problem was related with Integration Studio rather than Micro Integrator.

Integration Studio is Eclipse based and changing the encoding for Integration Studio resolved the problem for me.

Please refer to the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse) in order to update Integration Studio's encoding.